# C program-server function error

Tags: c, linux, function, sockets

I am trying to learn C and I can't get these apps working.  I am creating 2 apps client/server, where the client connects to a server via specified port, and sends a file name (text) to the server.  The server then takes the file name, runs it through a word count function and then responds to the client with filename/line/word/character count.  I have gotten the client and the server to connect and communicate but my problem is that I can't seem to pass the client input to the wordcount function properly.  Also, I'm not sure my function will return properly as I haven't found an appropriate method of returning a crafted string.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

char * wordcount(char *cfile){
    int i = 0;
    int ccount = 0;
    int wcount = 0;
    int lcount = 0;
    char *fn = malloc(strlen(cfile+7));
    sprintf(fn, "/Files/%s", cfile);
    FILE *cfilename = fopen (fn, "r");
    while ((i = fgetc(cfilename)) != EOF){
        if (i == '\n') {
            lcount++;
        }
        if (i == '\t' || i == ' '){
            wcount++;
        }
        ccount++;
    }
    printf("%c contains %d words, %d characters and %d lines.\n", cfile, wcount, ccount, lcount);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sock, newSock, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];  
    int index = 5;
    int lowPortNum = 2500 + (10 * index);
    int highPortNum = 2500 + (10 * index) + 9;  
/* Check for proper amount of args */
     if (argc < 2){
         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: No port specified. Exiting...\n");
         printf("NOTE: Port must be between %d & %d.\n",lowPortNum,highPortNum);
         exit(1);
     } 
/* Create socket by using args to form components */
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock < 0){
        error("ERROR: Could not create socket");
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        error("ERROR: Binding failed.");
        return 1;
    }
/* Start listening on socket */
    listen(sock, 5);
    puts("Server is waiting for connection...");
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
/* Accept connection from incoming client */
    newSock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newSock < 0){
        error("ERROR: Accept failed.");
    }
/* Read message from the client */
        bzero(buffer, 256);
        if (read(newSock, buffer, 255) < 0){
            error("ERROR: Cannot read from socket.");
        }
//debug 
        printf("client msg read: %s\n",buffer);
/* Send message to the client */
//wordcount(buffer);
        if (write(newSock , wordcount(buffer) , 100) < 0){
            error("ERROR: Cannot write to socket.");
        }
    close(newSock);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I can't seem to pass the client input to the wordcount function properly". Please explain what the problem is exactly. That is, what exactly is the problem when you call `wordcount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you've made a mistake here:

```
char *fn = malloc(strlen(cfile+7));
sprintf(fn, "/Files/%s", cfile);
```

You probably meant this:

```
char fn[strlen(cfile) + 8];
sprintf(fn, "/Files/%s", cfile);
```

You might notice that I've rearranged it a little; I think you wanted to add 7 to the return value of `strlen`, not to the argument of `strlen`. I've written 8 instead, because the extra 1 is for a `'\0'` which goes at the end of your string; that's extremely important. When you're crafting strings, **always remember to make space for the `'\0'`.**

Additionally, I've changed your `malloc` to a variable-length array. You really don't need to use dynamic storage duration (e.g. `malloc`) for this; **try to prefer automatic storage duration unless you absolutely need dynamic storage duration.**

Especially considering that your code leaks memory (which is the precise reason to avoid it unless you absolutely need it). Perhaps valgrind would be a useful tool in your development environment? **Always remember to `free` any memory you have `malloc`d.**

---

There's another error here:

```
FILE *cfilename = fopen (fn, "r");
while ((i = fgetc(cfilename)) != EOF){
```

Supposing `fopen` returns `NULL` (probably to indicate that the file doesn't exist), the calls to `fgetc` following it are clearly going to fail in disastrous ways. I think you meant something like this:

```
FILE *cfilename = fopen (fn, "r");
if (cfilename == NULL) {
    /* XXX: HANDLE THIS ERROR! We'll get to this later... */
}
while ((i = fgetc(cfilename)) != EOF){
```

... and similarly, you've forgotten to `fclose` that file that was `fopen`d. **Always remember to `fclose` files that you have `fopen`d.**

---

> ... my problem is that I can't seem to pass the client input to the `wordcount` function properly

Providing the mistakes mentioned earlier are fixed, you should be able to safely pass the message received from your socket to `wordcount` as you have in your comment, without crashes or resource leaks: `wordcount(buffer);`...

You can try that if you like, but bear with me for a moment longer because you have other requirements to assess.

---

> I'm not sure my function will return properly as I haven't found an appropriate method of returning a crafted string.

Think about how standard library functions handle this. You've used one of them here: `sprintf(fn, "/Files/%s", cfile);`. By accepting the destination (`fn`) for the string as an argument, `sprintf` allows you to use whichever storage duration you like. Additionally, this allows `sprintf` to return some other `int` value (which you can look up in [the `sprintf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html) in your own time)...

If you design your function to write to a destination pointed to by an argument, like `sprintf` (and others) do, you'll be able to use your function however you like (e.g. automatic *or* dynamic storage duration?), too. You'll be able to return an `int` value indicating success or failure (e.g. when the `fopen` call fails), too.

Consider the following function, which doesn't even need a return value because there are no error modes:

```
typedef unsigned long long ullong;
void fcount(FILE *f, ullong *char_count, ullong *word_count, ullong *line_count)
{
    rewind(f);
    *char_count = 0;
    *word_count = 0;
    *line_count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int c = fgetc(f);
        switch (c) {
            case EOF:  return;
            case '\n': (*line_count)++;
            case '\t':
            case ' ':  (*word_count)++;
            default:   (*char_count)++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now consider this wrapper of that function, which *does* require a return value

```
int count(char *destination, char *filename) {
    char fn[strlen(filename) + 8];
    sprintf(fn, "/files/%s", filename);

    FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        /* Note: This exit code is defined within <stdlib.h> */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ullong char_count, word_count, line_count;
    count(f, &char_count, &word_count, &line_count);
    fclose(f);

    sprintf(destination, "%s contains %llu words, %llu characters and %llu lines.\n", filename, word_count, char_count, line_count);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now you can tell if your function fails or succeeds, just like many of the standard library functions! Yay!

```
char buf[128];
count(buf, file_name);
printf("%s", buf);
```

You can also access the string you intended to write... Is this all flowing together?

Comment: Thank you @undefined-behaviour for your excellent explanation and thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I truly appreciate your help!  I have some questions.  Why should I use long instead of int?  Is count calling itself or is that supposed to be fcount in the count wrapper?  I'm testing your suggestion and it does seem to work but I am getting gibberish returned.  Is there something I should do with the "buffer" I receive from the client before passing it to the count function?

Comment: @dvspawn `int` is guaranteed to be able to represent values between -32767 and 32767. Your implementation may extend that range, but there's no guarantee that every implementation will. It's not uncommon for files to be greater than 32KB in size, and overflowing a signed integer is technically undefined behaviour (a bad thing). You'd surely want a larger range than that...

Comment: @dvspawn `unsigned long long` (`typedef`d to `ullong` in the code I presented) is guaranteed to be able to represent values between 0 and 18446744073709551615; there are no negatives, hence the `unsigned` part of the type, and that makes more sense because there are definitely no files that large in this day and age. Even if it somehow manages to overflow, unsigned integer overflow is well defined to wrap back to 0.

Comment: @dvspawn The `buffer` you have in your code, after the `bzero` and the `read`, is safe to pass as the second argument to the `count` I have written.